# How to declare a negative number on a QTableView using SQlite

Tags: sqlite, qt5

I am designing a major user interface with several fields.
In order to shrink the problem I created a small minimal application with 5 columns: name, image, dataDatabase, dateTime and coordNumber.

I have a MainWindow with a QTableView, as soon as I right click inside the QTableView an AddItemDialog opens up with:

```
1) nameLineEdit
2) ImLineEdit
3) imageLineEdit
4) dateTimeEdit
5) numLineEdit
```

The issue that I have is that I can't find a way to accept the 5) numLineEdit through the AddItemDialog **when the number is negative.**
Currently it only saves positive numbers. How to handle this exception?

I read from [official document](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) but I could not figure out. However always [from this official source](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) it seems that a negative number must be interpreted as "no limit" value. The explanation was short and didn't provide any useful small example, so I am still not sure how to proceed.

I am including the most important parts of the application below with the related description of the procedure I followed:

I created an Item with the fields **item.h**:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(const double dateTime,
         const QString &name = "", const QString &image = "",
         int num, const QByteArray &imagesData = QByteArray());
    QString name() const { return mName; }
    QString image() const { return mImage; }
    QByteArray imagesData() const { return mImagesData; }
    double dateTime() const { return mDateTime; }
    int num() const { return mNumberCoord; } 
private:
    QString mName;
    QString mImage;
    QByteArray mImagesData;
    double mDateTime;
    int mNumberCoord
};
```

and its related **item.cpp**

```
Item::Item(const double dateTime, int num,
           const QString &name, const QString &image, int num,
           const QByteArray &imagesData) : 
    mName(name),
    mImage(image),
    mImagesData(imagesData),
    mDateTime(dateTime),
    mNumberCoord(num)
{
}
```

I created a **database.h** table that will contain the parameters as follows:

```
class dataBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit dataBase(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool inizializationDataBase(const QString &nameDataBase);
    bool configureDataBase();
    QString getError() const { return mError; }
    bool addItem(const Item &item);
private:
    QSqlDatabase mDatabase;
    QString mError;
};
```

And its related **database.cpp** file - I am only including the most important piece of the code for this file:

```
#define CREATE_TABLE \
     " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fish_Table" \
     " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
     ", name TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", image TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", dataDataBase BLOB NOT NULL" \
     ", dateTime DOUBLE NOT NULL" \
     ", num INTEGER NOT NULL)"  

dataBase::dataBase(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

bool dataBase::addItem(const Item &item) {
    QSqlQuery q;
    q.prepare("INSERT INTO Fish_Table (name, image, dataDatabase, dateTime, num) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    q.addBindValue(item.name());
    q.addBindValue(item.image());
    q.addBindValue(item.imagesData());
    q.addBindValue(item.dateTime());
    q.addBindValue(item.num());
    bool ok = q.exec();
    if (!ok) {
        mError = q.lastError().text();
    }
    return ok;
}
```

and finally the **AddItemDialog.cpp** that contains the fields I am trying to pass to the QTableView of the MainWindow.

**AddItemDialog.cpp**

```
void AddItemDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QFile dataBase(ui->imageLineEdit->text());
    if (!dataBase.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", dataBase.errorString());
        return;
    }
    mItem = Item(ui->dateTimeEdit->dateTime(),
                 ui->nameLineEdit->text(),
                 ui->ImLineEdit->text(),
                 ui->numLineEdit->text(),
                 dataBase.readAll());
    dataBase.close();
    accept();
}
```

I expect to save either positive or negative numbers on the QTableView, but as of now I can only save positive numbers. How to handle this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is yes, it is possible to handle negative numbers. For some reasons I thought that `SQL` was not able to do that but below is a small example of how to handle that exception:

```
#define CREATE_TABLE \
     " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fish_Table" \
     " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
     ", name TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", image TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", dataDataBase BLOB NOT NULL" \
     ", dateTime DOUBLE NOT NULL" \
     ", num INTEGER NOT NULL)"  

dataBase::dataBase(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

bool dataBase::addItem(const Item &item) {
    QSqlQuery q;
    q.prepare("INSERT INTO Fish_Table (name, image, dataDatabase, dateTime, num) VALUES (name,descriptionOfImage,BLOB(actual image), put date&time,-200)");
    q.addBindValue(item.name());
    q.addBindValue(item.image());
    q.addBindValue(item.imagesData());
    q.addBindValue(item.dateTime());
    q.addBindValue(item.num());
    bool ok = q.exec();
    if (!ok) {
        mError = q.lastError().text();
    }
    return ok;
}
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/unary-operators-negative?view=sql-server-2017) is also a very valuable source.

If also there is any need to turn a positive number into a negative number than this is a possible solution:

```
UPDATE Table
SET field= (field * -1)
Where SIGN(field) = -1
```

[Also this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/23/sql-server-introduction-to-function-sign/) is very useful in case someone needs the `SQL` code for an additional source.